# ¿Cómo solucionar Error 1292 insertando registros?

Tags: mysql, sql

En base de datos de actividad selecciono distintos valores de una columna y sumo el resultado agrupado de este modo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`grouped_country`), SUM(`sales_out_revenue_actual`) as lalala
FROM genuine_2016
GROUP BY grouped_country
```

Eso me dos columnas con resultados deseados. Pero cuando intento hacer insert esos resultados en otra tabla de este modo:

```
INSERT INTO genuine_fy16_results (result_owner, result_result)
SELECT DISTINCT(`grouped_country`), SUM(`sales_out_revenue_actual`) as lalala
FROM genuine_2016
GROUP BY grouped_country;
```

Es cuando me da el error:

> [Err] 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '83,87'

Comment: habría que revisar el resultado de la primera consulta a ver si alguno de los `lalala` no es un número válido. Puede que para insertar tengas que castear `lalala` como número

Comment: Todos son números válidos sin espacios, sin comas ... incluso cuando la columna donde hago insert resultado, la de `lalala` la he puesto como `VARCHAR (255)`, pero sige mostrándome el mismo error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este mensaje aparece ya que estas intentando insertar un número (`DOUBLE`) en una columna que espera una cadena (`VARCHAR(255)`).

### Soluciones:

- Cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna `result_result` a `DOUBLE`.
- Utiliza la función [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) para convertir el número en una cadena. Ej:

  ```
  CAST(SUM(`sales_out_revenue_actual`) AS VARCHAR(255))
  ```
- Desactiva el modo estricto (`SET sql_mode = '';`), el error debe convertirse en una advertencia.

Comment: De momento no he encontrado la solución, pero gracias a ti he encontrado el error: la columna que sumo tiene datos no numéricos... ahora me pregunto ¿porqué me deja sumar con `SUM(´columna´)` pero no insertar lo sumado ... bueno, gracias Marcos!

Comment: @Lukas, no, el problema es que el resultado de `SUM(columna)` es un número y lo estas intentando guardar en un columna `VARCHAR(X)`; como tienes activado el modo estricto te arroja error.

Comment: Debo ejecutar `SET sql_mode = '';` cómo cualquier otra query? Porque lo he hecho y me sigue saliendo el error...

Comment: @Lukas, debes realizar ambas en la misma ejecución. Ejemplo: `SET sql_mode = ''; INSERT INTO genuine_fy16_results (result_owner, result_result)....;`

Comment: GRACIAS GRACIAS !!!

Comment: @MarcosGallardo a mí me pareció que el error original era insertando los valores en un campo numérico. La solución de pasarlo a varchar 255 fue algo temporal, pero creo que no va a quedar como se quería originalmente

Comment: @amenadiel, en la pregunta el OP menciona que si hace el `SELECT` obtiene el resultado esperado y sin errores. Luego al hacer el `INSERT... SELECT...` si obtiene error, es decir, el problema esta en el tipo de dato de la columna `result_result`

Comment: Claro, pero el SELECT traía valores no numéricos, que eran triviales de desplegar, pero no triviales de insertar. Modificando la columna a varchar pudo insertar, pero ahora no podrá volver el tipo de columna a su estado original sin limpiar la data no numérica. En algún momento del flujo tendrá que hacer ese paso

Comment: @amenadiel, creo que hay o una mala interpretación de tu parte en base a los datos que se suman (_si es por el 1er comentario del OP, el interpreto mal mi respuesta, ver mi comentario debajo_) o hay algo que yo me perdí.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo es posible. En realidad sólo estoy suponiendo lo que el OP quería hacer originalmente